# PDFsharp drawing images at 72 DPI, if more resolution it is drawn "smaller"

Tags: pdfsharp

I'm drawing an image of 100 x 100 pixels in a PDFSharp document.

The image is drawn using:

```
 g.DrawImage(image, new Point(x, y));
```

The issue here is that if I draw a rectangle starting in the same coordinates x,y and using 100x100 as dimensiones... the rectangle is larger than the image.

If I use the other overloads in DrawImage, setting the container rectangle, the image fits the rectangle but it loses quality (it is enlarged).

[image: The logo in the PDF looks like this]

I think it is a problem of different resolutions or something like that.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I resized the image to 133x133 to fit the 100x100 rectangle. What is the reason of this difference? A 33% difference.

**MY SOLUTION:** When retrieving the image and scaling it to fit the rectangle, you need to take into account that the size of your image is in PIXELS and when you draw in the PDF it is in points. If your image is in 96 DPI, you need to increase its dimension multiplying by "96/72" (that is the 33% I got), and that way you will see what you expect (even if you draw it using a container rectangle or just the starting coordinates).

Set `image.Interpolate = false;` to disable anti-aliasing and increase the sharpness of the small image.

Comment: Time to update the thread title: PDFsharp (s is lower case) draws images with the correct size, but not with the size you expect. Set your image to 72 DPI and the image will fill the rectangle.

Comment: Your "solution" does not make much sense. PDFsharp uses points as the default unit and one point is 1/72 inch. If you draw images without specifying a size, they will be drawn with the size specified in the image file (which is 96 DPI for many images created under Windows). A "point" is not a pixel, it is 1/72 inch. I cannot recommend resizing all images just to be able to use `DrawImage` without specifying a size.

Comment: Nope... My images are larger... I resized it to 100x100 now I'm resizing it to 133×133 (if it is 96Dpi)  to fit the 100x100 points square.  Drawing it with or without specifying size is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "pixels" in PDF. DrawImage has overloads that allow to draw the image with a specific size.

If the size is omitted (as you do), the size will be determined by the DPI setting of the image. Could it be your image is set to 96 DPI?

The rectangle 100x100 uses points - and there are 72 points per inch.

The image does not lose quality when you set the size. The "quality loss" depends on the zoom level of the viewer.

You can set a hint to prevent Adobe Reader from anti-aliasing the image.

Update:
Set `image.Interpolate = false;` to disable anti-aliasing.

Comment: Well, if you have a 100x100 image displayed in a 133x133 square, you are indeed stretching the image. So, it is better in this case to start with a 133x133 image, and not having it stretched... and for doing so, I will need to get an image taking into account this convertion ratio (96/72=1.333). Thanks.

Comment: @Romias PDF is a vector format by nature and it does make no difference whether the image has 100x100 pixels or 133x133 pixels. Well, with 133x133 pixels the quality is inherently higher, but the "stretching" happens when the image is drawn, depending on the zoom level set in the PDF viewer. PDF uses points and points are just a unit like cm or mm or inch. Whichever image size you choose, it will always get stretched when it is drawn on the screen.

Comment: I get that... I don't pretend to see a sharp image at 600%. But know how it works, I can do this conversion in order to have a sharper image at the size of the page (A4) on screen and printing.

Comment: Have you tried `image.Interpolate = false;`? Small images will look sharper at high zoom levels with this option.

Comment: I will try that! Thanks!!