# Unable to scan ZXing.NET barcodes

Tags: c#, .net, zxing, pdfsharp

I am using a template in which I have to fit many barcodes in a sheet. So, I would need small barcodes. I am using ZXing to generate barcodes and then saving them in a memory stream and printing them on a pdf using PDFSharp.

I can scan the barcode with my phone if I zoom in the page but with normal page resolution  I cannot scan them. What I am doing wrong? Is there anyway I can print good quality barcodes on the pdf. Currently, the barcodes seem blurry.

This is my code

```
BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter()
{
    Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
    Options = new EncodingOptions
    {
        Height = 100,
        Width = 180,
        PureBarcode = false,
        Margin = 10,
    },
};

string content = @"*" + textBox1.Text + "*"; 
var bitmap = writer.Write(content);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                GeneratePDF(ms);
            }
```

Then with PDFSharp

```
            // Create a new PDF document
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

            // Create an empty page
            PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

            // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

            XImage pic = XImage.FromStream(ms);

            gfx.DrawImage(pic, 220, 120, 110, 23);
```

If barcode content is large, then I am increasing the width because its then barcodes lines are overlapping each other.

```
gfx.DrawImage(pic, 10, 10, 135, 20);
```

I found this -

[Barcode generator for small size image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734055/barcode-generator-for-small-size-image)

I set `barcode.Setresolution(300,300)`

still my barcodes are blurry.

Comment: It appears to me that the barcode is being created at one size (160w x 80h) and then drawn into the PDF at a different size. That means some interpolation, which is likely to blur it, is being done. Can you create the barcode at the exact size it will be drawn?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried setting the height of barcode as 23 and width as 110( same as what I am printing in pdf) but it increased the size of barcode. I need smaller barcodes and with earlier setting I was getting smaller barcodes. And barcode image is still not crisp.

Comment: Ah, of course, PDFsharp uses points, not pixels. Have you seen [PDFsharp drawing images at 72 DPI, if more resolution it is drawn "smaller"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491460/pdfsharp-drawing-images-at-72-dpi-if-more-resolution-it-is-drawn-smaller), where setting `.Interpolate = false` helped?

Comment: @AndrewMorton i tried it didnt help. I then tried saving barcode as image. The image is crisp there but in pdf it is blur. Do you think it is because im using memory stream?

Comment: Nope, tried printing image as well still blur

Comment: @AndrewMorton I fixed it. Increased the width of the barcode as 400. Set the resolution as 300X300. Set interpolation as false and changed to gfx.DrawImage(pic, 10, 10, barcode.PointWidth, barcode.PointHeight); Thanks for you help!!!

Comment: If you've found a solution, please consider posting it as an answer rather than a comment. This makes it easier for other users to see that your question has been answered. Please note that [Stack Overflow actively encourages people to post answers to their own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. Increased the width of the barcode as 400. Set the resolution as 300X300. Set interpolation as false and changed to `gfx.DrawImage(pic, 10, 10, barcode.PointWidth, barcode.PointHeight);`